# Multiplication of Square roots in the form of (a+b) (a-b)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Question: What is the value of :
>   $$\left(\sqrt{24+5\sqrt{23}}\right)\left(\sqrt{24-5\sqrt{23}}\right)$$

I tried to apply $(a+b)(a-b) = a^2 - b^2$ but that is wrong.

Please suggest another method.

Comment: Why is it wrong?  $\sqrt{24 + 5\sqrt{23}}\sqrt{24-5\sqrt {23}} = \sqrt {24^2 - 5^2*23}=....$

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=24, b=5\sqrt{23}$.

Then our expression is $\sqrt{a+b}\sqrt{a-b}=\sqrt{(a+b)(a-b)}=\sqrt{a^2-b^2}=\sqrt{24^2-25\cdot23}=\sqrt{1}=1$

Therefore the answer is $D$.

Answer (score 2):

Why was that wrong?

$(\sqrt{24 + 5\sqrt {23}})(\sqrt{24 - 5\sqrt{23}}=$

$\sqrt {(24 + 5\sqrt {23})(24-5\sqrt{23})}=$

$\sqrt{24^2 - 5^2*23}=\sqrt{24^2 - 25*23}$.

Now you can plug that into a calculator and get $\sqrt{24^2 - 25*23} = 1$.

Or you can be a smart-alec and note

$\sqrt{24^2 - 25*23} =\sqrt{24^2 - (24+1)(24-1)} =$

$\sqrt{24^2 - (24^2 - 1)} =\sqrt{1} = 1$.

So the answer is $1$.

Comment: That smart-alec move tho...

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{(24+5\sqrt{23})(24-5\sqrt{23})}$$
$$=\sqrt{24^2-(5\sqrt{23})^2}$$
$$=\sqrt{576-575}$$
$$=1.$$